# xenon balast and igniter testing

Tags: bmw

I have a BMW E46 with EOM xenon headlight, but they stopped working. I checked and BMW xenon headlights have two pieces: balast and igniter. Is it possible to determine which one is broken?

I added the [scheme](http://www.realoem.com/bmw/showparts.do?model=EV53&mospid=47725&btnr=63_0550&hg=63&fg=05):
[image: Scheme of BMW E46 EOM xenon headlights]

balast is 15, igniter is 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did both sides stop working? 
If yes, it could be the module that sits behind the headlight switch.
If no, then switch the igniter or balast from left to right to find the culprit.

Comment: I am actually experiencing this now. For me, it was easy to determine that it was the ignitor (It was burned). But I did switch the balast and bulb to the other side to see if they sere still working.